# how to count the number of times a file is viewed

Tags: java, eclipse

web application contains a separate URL for each file stored.when you click the URL, the file is retrieved. how do you count the number of times each file is viewed.

Comment: when the web application requests the file, increment a counter associated with it. The easiest way is to have a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option would be add a ServletFilter in which you intercept those URL and increment a counter in a database to each file (based on URL path)